# Converting a Linq Query to a cumstom Type

Tags: linq-to-objects

I am having some problem when using linq and lambda expression. I have an object of Type Trip.

`

```
List<Trip> trip = newTrips.Select(x=>x).ToList();
 IEnumerable<Trip> data = trip.GroupBy(y=> new {
                            y.StartingNode,
                            y.EndingNode,
                            y.PathNumber}).Cast<Trip>();

List <Trip> listAgain = data.ToList();  // This is where i get the error
```

cannot implicitly convert system.collection.generics.list to DataObjects.Trip

`
I Need to convert the result obtained from linq to a list object. Or is there any other better way to acheive this.

Comment: what is the datatype for `new Trips`?

Comment: What's not clear to me is what you're hoping to get out of this query. You're grouping an `IEnumerable<Trip>` by an anonymous variable, then you're trying to cast the groups back to the type `Trip`. You're missing some code or you're just doing the wrong query. What's your intent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`trip.GroupBy(...)` does not return an `IEnumerable<Trip>`. It returns an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<'a, Trip>>`, where `'a` is an anonymous type created for the `new {...}` objects.

Those `IGrouping<'a, Trip>` objects are collections, and cannot be cast directly to a `Trip`.

If you want just a single object per group, do:

```
IEnumerable<Trip> data = trip
    .GroupBy(y => new {
        y.StartingNode,
        y.EndingNode,
        y.PathNumber
    })
    .Select(g => g.First());
List<Trip> listAgain = data.ToList();
```

Alternatively, if you wanted all the trip objects, but grouped nicely by their start/end nodes and their path number, do:

```
IEnumerable<Trip> data = trip
    .GroupBy(y => new {
        y.StartingNode,
        y.EndingNode,
        y.PathNumber
    })
    .SelectMany(g => g);
List<Trip> listAgain = data.ToList();
```

The `IGrouping` objects are templated by the original type, and return `Trip` objects for both *.First()* and *.SelectMany()*.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation and working. I got my stuff working

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert the result of `GroupBy` to `Trip` - it does not return a `Trip`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx

Note, that why the error is on the third assignment is because `GroupBy` and `Cast` are deferred.